# Meaning of "Know the local drug scene for yourself" in “What Every Kid Should Be Able to Do by Age Sixteen”

Tags: phrase-meaning

From “[What Every Kid Should Be Able to Do by Age Sixteen](https://hayleytalbot.com/category/adventure/)” by [Audrey Sutherland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audrey_Sutherland):

> - Read a topographic map and a chart
> - **Know the local drug scene for yourself**
> - Handle a boat safely and competently (canoe, kayak, skiff, sailboat)

The bolded phrase seems out of sorts with the rest of the list. Does it mean "a kid ot 16 should know where to get illegal drugs"? It puzzled me. I'm not a native speaker, maybe I'm missing something.

What is the true meaning of this?

Comment: The way you put it gives the wrong emphasis. I'd paraphrase it 'Be aware that drug-dealing does occur in your neighbourhood, know the extent of it, and the places and people to avoid.'

Comment: Rather than knowing where to get drugs – knowing how to refuse them. A 16-y-o who knows how to get around safely.

Comment: Urban kids often have to choose between taking a "safer" but longer  route to school, or the more dangerous "druggie" areas where violent  disputes may happen.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - I knew the places and people to avoid, and those to go to.

Comment: Wow, that's a vague sentence and one easily misconstrued. My first reaction was just like yours, OP. Perhaps when this list was written would preclude our initial understanding.